# How to retrieve only authorization.action via PS

Tags: azure, powershell

Trying to retrieve the value of Authorization.action from *Get-AzActivityLog* | select-Object but I am having difficulty filtering my results down to what I need.

When running the below, I get results but when I pipe to *Select-Object* to only return the specified values, I get values for all except Autorization.action. Fairly new so not sure how to accomplish this and not finding documentation that clarifies to me online. Obviously Authorization.action is not correct but I can't seem to find a solution.

```
Get-AzActivityLog -ResourceId $sa.Id `
                -StartTime ((Get-Date).AddDays($timeframe)) `
                -Status Succeeded `
                | where {$_.Authorization.action -like "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/regenerateKey/action"} `
                | Select-Object Authorization.action, EventTimestamp, ResourceGroupName, ResourceId
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNjPU.png)

Thanks for any insight in to this.

Comment: `Select-Object Authorization.action,...` -> `Select-Object @{Name='AuthorizationAction';Expression={$_.Authorization.action}},...`

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the direction. Gave me what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in Multiple ways :

```
Get-AzActivityLog -ResourceId $sa.Id `
                -StartTime ((Get-Date).AddDays($timeframe)) `
                -Status Succeeded `
                | where {$_.Authorization.action -like "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/regenerateKey/action"} `
                | Select-Object {$_.Authorization.action}, EventTimestamp, ResourceGroupName, ResourceId
```

**Or**

Like Mathias Mentioned :

```
Get-AzActivityLog -ResourceId $sa.Id `
                -StartTime ((Get-Date).AddDays($timeframe)) `
                -Status Succeeded `
                | where {$_.Authorization.action -like "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/regenerateKey/action"} `
                | Select-Object @{Name='AuthorizationAction';Expression={$_.Authorization.action}}, EventTimestamp, ResourceGroupName, ResourceId
```

The Reason Being Select-Object chooses the immediate property of the object. However, in your case the Authorization.Action is one level down being a complex property. So you will have to evaluate the expression.

Also you could use the -ExpandProperty parameter to expand a complex property.

```
 Select-Object Authorization -ExpandProperty Authorization | Select-Object Action
```